# How could one create a man sized cylinder be created with woodworking?

Tags: wood, framing, woodworking

The goal is to create a cylinder shaped, ribbed shell with wood, and what Evers necessary to hold it together. Something like the following image:

[image]

The idea is that the internal area of the circles is empty space. each ring would be supported with with horizontal beams. But how would the circles be fabricated out of wood? Any tools, materials, methodologies, plausible suggestions etc would be the goal of answering this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with sheets of plywood, draw out the shapes you want, and use a reciprocating saw.

Strength will be decided by width of the rings and plywood thickness and grade.

If you want to automate that, use a ShopBot.

Answer (score 3):

If you want near perfect circles, rig a router with a trammel beam rotating around a fixed point. You'll get repeatable sizes with a good edge.